# Validation and ComplexTypes

Tags: validation, breeze, complextype

I have read BreezeJS documention about validation and ComplexTypes. To my knowledge, there should be no reason for that scenario to work.

We use *breeze.directives.js*. BreezeJS version is 1.4.14. In our application, Person-entity has property `PhoneNumber` which is ComplexType. Person-entity is binded to a view in AngularJS app. For validation we used the example from Code Camper SPA.  Person-entity gets validated and zValidate works as expected. To our surprise PhoneNumber-complextype gets validated too , but validation errors dont show up. So it seems there's problem with zValidation and ComplexTypes.

Anyone know if it should work ? Or are we just missing something?

Note: DocCode or any other sample didn't include this scenario implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zValidate was not written to support ComplexTypes. zValidate is part proof-of-concept and part invitation to the community to contribute. It demonstrates one way to expose Breeze validation to the UI, declaratively, with an Angular directive. We invite you to fork it and offer improvements or alternatives. We're eager to tell the world about your work :-)

Comment: This is good to know. We will look into it and maybe contribute something useful to other BreezeJS users.